# Regex for soccer data

Tags: regex, csv, sed

Why isn't my regex working? It just returns back the original file. My file looks like this (for a few hundred lines):

```
1    Germany    1765    0   Equal   
2    Argentina  1631    0   Equal   
3    Colombia   1488    1   Up  
4    Netherlands    1456    -1  Down    
5    Belgium    1444    0   Equal   
6    Brazil 1291    1   Up  
7    Uruguay    1243    -1  Down    
8    Spain  1228    -1  Down    
9    France 1202    1   Up  
...
192  US Virgin Islands  28  -1  Down
```

And I want this:

```
Germany,1
Argentina,2
Colombia,3
...
US Virgin Islands,192
```

This is the regex I tried:

```
 sed 's/\([0-9]*\)\t\([a-zA-Z]*\)/\2,\1/g' <fifa.csv >fifa.csv
```

But it just returns the original file.
EDIT:
Now I tried

```
sed 's/\([0-9]*\)\t\([a-zA-Z]*\)/\2,\1/g' <fifa.csv >fifa.csv
```

and got

```
,1 Germany,,1765Equal,0,
,2 Argentina,,1631Equal,0,
,3 Colombia,,1488Up,1,
,4 Netherlands,,1456-Down,1,
,5 Belgium,,1444Equal,0,
```

Comment: What makes you think the letters `tab` will match a tab character in the input? You probably need to use an escape sequence - `\t` would be my guess.

Comment: Did the input are tab separated?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes, it's a word or number followed by a tab.

Comment: I'm asking if there any tab exists after the country name?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes, every column is tab-delimited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below sed command if the fields are tab-separated.

```
sed 's/^\([0-9]\+\)\t\([^\t]*\).*/\2,\1/' file
```

Add the inline-edit option `-i` to save the changes made.

```
sed -i 's/^\([0-9]\+\)\t\([^\t]*\).*/\2,\1/' file
```

`^` means start of the line anchor. `+` would repeat the previous character one or more times. Basic sed uses BRE so you need to escape the `+` to do the functionality of repeating the previous character one or more times. `[^\t]*` matches any character but not of `\t` tab character zero or more times.

Comment: Shouldn't you add a /g' at the end?

Comment: no, the replacement occurs only one time for each line. So we don't need to go for `g` modifier.

Comment: Also what does ^ and + and ^\t and .* mean? Could you please explain the regex a little?

Comment: So why not use [0-9]*?

Comment: @RenéG are you sure there must be a number at the first? If there is no number at first then you could use `[0-9]*`. Example, if the input is `\tGermany`, you would get `Germany,` if you used `[0-9]*` but if you use `[0-9]\+`, this regex won't do the replacement on this particular line because `+` ensures that there must be at-least a single digit.

Comment: Yes. Also I just noticed that each line of the output has a space at the beginning for some reason.

Comment: I don't know how spaces appear at the first. Use this to remove the leading spaces. `sed 's/^\([0-9]\+\)\t\([^\t]*\).*/\2,\1/;s/^ *//' file`

Answer (score 1):

The following is what you are looking for. The `-i` option specifies that files are to be edited in-place.

```
sed -i 's/^\([0-9]\+\)\t\([^\t]*\).*/\2,\1/' fifa.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{print( $2 "," $1)}' YourFile
```

not a sed but easier to manage

Comment: Won't work for country names that contain spaces, like "US Virgin Islands".

Comment: So another sed `sed 's/[0-9]*  *\([^0-9]*\) .*/\1,&/;s/ *\(,[0-9]*\).*/\1/' YourFile`